# Separate possible duplicate text from actual question text in summary

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, question-summary

When a question is marked as a duplicate, the duplicate blockquote bleeds into the summary, which then leads to confusion over where the duplicate title ends and the question body begins.

Consider this question:
[Duplicate Consuion http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8536/dupconfusion.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8536/dupconfusion.png)

What's the name of the duplicate here? Is it "Keeping folders synced between several machines I own" or "Keeping folders synced between several machines"? (this isn't the greatest example, but you get the idea) Why is the duplicate warning bleeding into my question anyway?

How could this be fixed? Well, why not insert a simple pipe character or a dash? Both are much less intrusive and complicated than a new line or new markup. Using this I can actually see where the title ends and the question begins when titles don't have punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's confusing, click through to the question to see it.

Note removing formatting and line breaks already causes confusion in summaries in many more cases; differentiating duplicates is only a small part of that larger problem.

That larger problem, as a whole, doesn't seem to be a big deal or worth worrying about.  However, changing summaries could easily decrease usability of the question list, and that is something that should definitely be avoided.

Comment: The issue is annoying but acceptable I guess.